# Iteratively (or recursively?) filter directory and copy results to new directory

Tags: python, recursion, filter, directory, os.walk

I’m new to Python and have been teaching myself with textbooks and StackOverflow. I seem to learn best from real world examples from this site. I’m hoping someone can help me with my current problem.

I have a directory (folder) with about 1,000 files. The files have names with prefixes (patterns) such as, `aaa_*`, `bbb_*`, `ccc_*` and so on. I would like to iterate through the directory and copy all the files that have the specified prefix and move them to a new directory with that prefix name. For example, find all the `aaa_*` files in `/my_dir_path` and copy them to `/my_new_dir_path/aaa` and likewise all the `bbb_*` to `/my_new_dir_path/bbb`. The new directories have already been created.

The following simple, boilerplate, script works for copying one of the prefix patterns to a new directory:

```
dir = '/my_dir_path'
pattern = 'aaa_*'
dest = '/my_new_dir_path/aaa'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        source = (os.path.join(root, filename))
        shutil.copy2(source, dest)
```

What I’m struggling with is how to recursively run `fnmatch.filter` for my list of patterns and then, ultimately, output the files to their own directory.

I have tried writing a number of different function definitions with the list of patterns as `*args`, but would typically get an error message that “filter() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)”. (I apologize for not having code examples to show you here. I’ve been through so many versions in the last few days that I don’t have any one representative function definition.)

I’m such a novice that I don’t know if `fnmatch.filter` can even be made recursive or how to devise an alternative strategy. Then, there is the problem of how to store the resulting files from each pattern search into its own directory. I was thinking that I could create a dictionary in advance, e.g.,

```
my_dict = {'my_new_dir_path/aaa': 'aaa_*', 'my_new_dir_path/bbb': 'bbb_*'}
```

and store the resulting files as values under the appropriate key, but given that I haven’t even gotten the recursion to work (i.e., print) I haven’t worked on how to copy the results to a new directory.

Comment: I'm not clear on the desired result from the recursion.  Are you saying that you want to move files at multiple levels?  rename directories with a common prefix?

Comment: In the original directory, there are files: aaa_1, aaa_2, aaa_n, bbb_4, bbb_6, bbb_7 etc. I am trying to isolate all those that are 'aaa_*' and copy/move them to a folder labeled 'aaa' and take all the 'bbb_*' and move them to a folder labeled 'bbb'. The new directories (aaa, bbb etc.) have already been created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I haven't tested this since I don't have all of the files to test with. However, I would just make the "pattern" variable a list and add another for loop. I also changed the "dest" variable so we can just utilize the "patterns" list.

```
import os
import shutil
import fnmatch

dir = '/my_dir_path'
patterns = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
dest = '/my_new_dir_path/'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for pattern in patterns:
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern+'_*'):
            source = (os.path.join(root, filename))
            shutil.copy2(source, dest+pattern+'/')
```

Comment: Thanks! The second for loop accomplished the iteration. (I'm banging my head against the wall because I started this process with a second for loop. I see now where I made my error.) The task now is to isolate all the 'a-files' and copy them to their own dir (.../aaa) and do the same for the 'b-files' --> (.../bbb) etc. Currently, all the files are being copied to a single dir. I think I need to store the results of the "for filename" loop into a series of lists or dict so I can copy each iteration into its own dir. I’ll work with that code now. I’ll gladly accept suggestions. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed a mistake in my code. Originally, I had the last line as `shutil.copy2(source, dest+'pattern')`  Which would put all the files into a directory called "destination." The line as it is now (`shutil.copy2(source, dest+pattern+'/')`), it should put the files into it's own directory, whichever iteration of the "patterns" list it's currently in. That's the reason I left off the "_*" in the patterns list, so it could be used as part of the destination directory as well. I also added the +'/' for good measure.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your help. That did the trick. Before I knocked off last night I realized that I needed to add +'/ ', but I didn't notice the 'pattern' (string) error. I kept working with various code versions, but they all gave the same error because pattern was being treated as a string. I've added this mistake to my checklist of Python errors to look for when I'm troubleshooting code. Thanks again for the learning opportunity and for saving me lots of time.