# python: read labels in a text file and separate images into different folders based on labels

Tags: python

I have a set of images and a text file containing labels for these images. I want to categorize these images to different folders (images of the same category are put into the same folder) according to their labels.

The text file is organized as follows:

```
apple21.jpg apple
apple24.jpg apple
test8.jpg banana
training.jpg banana
F-01.jpg frenchfry 
F-12.jpg frenchfry burger
.....
```

The first column represents image names, and the second and the third (if any) are image category. If one image has multiple labels, it will be put into the multiple folders accordingly.

I am new to python. Anyone can help you to do this?

Comment: Try and learn some things about the language. Figure it out on your own maybe? We can help you with issues once you've tried something, but this site isn't for asking people to write code for you.

Comment: I post this issue mainly because I need to use it very soon. I will try to do on my own

Comment: Use `with open("filename.txt") as file:` and `data = file.readlines()` to get the contents of your text file. Now you have a list (data variable) to work with. Use a for loop to iterate through the lines and `.split(" ")` to separate each line's columns into another list.

As for moving each file to a different folder, the shutil module should be able to help with that. In fact, the last question I was looking at dealt with that (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40854483/iteratively-or-recursively-filter-directory-and-copy-results-to-new-directory)

Comment: @AndrewLamarra You are so helpful!!